# Tab to beginning of text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form:

```
<form>
    <div class="username">
        <label for="username">Email</label><br />
        <input type="text" class="field" value="Enter your email" name="email" id="id_email">
    </div>
    <div class="password">
        <label for="password">Password</label><br />
        <input type="password" class="field" name="password" id="id_password">
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to make it such that when a user tabs from one field to another it sets the selection at the beginning of the field, instead of highlighting the entire field's text. An example can be seen on the login form here: https://squareup.com/.

I have a function that sets the cursor at the beginning of the text input, `setCursorAtBeginning`, how would I accomplish the above using js or jQuery (preferable, if it can be done in it)?

Comment: You really shouldn't do this, it's not the behaviour people expect.

Comment: I want to do it only if the field=default value, check out the link above to see how it would work.

Comment: Instead of putting the default value (which seems to be more like a label anyway) into the `value` attribute better use `placeholder` for it.

Comment: Oh, I see...so you basically have two different elements there. That makes it much easier, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Nope, what I meant is `<input type="text" class="field" value="" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" id="id_email">`: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/8dLxp/

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `placeholder`. You either have it if your browser supports `@placeholder`, or you can use a polyfill.

## @placeholder

```
<form>
  <div class="username">
    <label for="username">Email</label><br />
    <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" id="id_email">
  </div>
  <div class="password">
    <label for="password">Password</label><br />
    <input type="password" class="field" name="password" id="id_password" placeholder="Enter your password">
  </div>
</form>​
```

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/NtG4d/).

## polyfill

If you want to use it in older browsers you can make use of the [HTML5 Placeholder jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder for it. The best way is to use it with some js for cross browser compatibility. Like this plugin http://mal.co.nz/code/jquery-placeholder/